# Unpredictable behaviour of DecimalFormat

Tags: java

I understand DecimalFormat uses HALF_EVEN rounding as default and it rounds towards the "nearest neighbor". 
But in some cases DecimalFormat has strange behaviour:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    System.out.println(df.getRoundingMode()); // returns HALF_EVEN

    System.out.println(df.format(12766.135)); // returns 12 766,14
    System.out.println(df.format(22766.135)); // returns 22 766,13
    System.out.println(df.format(12766.155)); // returns 12 766,16
    System.out.println(df.format(22766.155)); // returns 22 766,15
    System.out.println(df.format(12766.185)); // returns 12 766,18
    System.out.println(df.format(22766.185)); // returns 22 766,19

    System.out.println(df.format(12766.145)); // returns 12 766,15
    System.out.println(df.format(22766.145)); // returns 22 766,15
    System.out.println(df.format(12766.175)); // returns 12 766,17
    System.out.println(df.format(22766.175)); // returns 22 766,17
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Tested on java 1.8.0_141, Eclipse 4.6.3.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, and it's not a bug. It's a truncation problem.

Comment: Misquoted. It 'rounds towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.'

Comment: The problem is the use of floating point values.  Those values cannot be represented exactly, and the residual error is sometimes positive and sometimes negative around the actual value.

Comment: Thanks @jim-garrison, I know floating point values are not represented exactly, that´s why I used `DecimalFormat`. I would expect `format` method
would handle this problem.